# get property's value inside html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a custom helper "My" and I would like to get value of the used property in it.

I'm calling it like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<VMThatHasAllTheseProps>" %>
<%=Html.My("Hi") %>
<%=Html.EditorFor(o => o.Prop) %> \\uses Html.My in the My.ascx template

<%=Html.My("[0].My") %>
<%=Html.My("[1].My") %>
```

and the helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString My(this HtmlHelper html, string prop, object value = null)
{
//get value of the used property here
}
```

at the moment I do like this:

```
 //get val from model
            if (value == null && html.ViewData.Model != null)
            {
                var p = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(html.ViewData.Model).Find(prop, false);

                if (p != null) value = p.GetValue(html.ViewData.Model);
            }

            //get val from model metada
            if(value == null && html.ViewData.ModelMetadata != null)
            {
                var p = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model).Find(prop, false);
                if (p != null) value = p.GetValue(html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model);
            }

            //get val from viewdata
            if (value == null && html.ViewData.ContainsKey(prop))
                value = html.ViewData[prop];
```

but obviously it doesn't work for the `"[0].My"`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're passing the property names, etc as strings instead of just passing the value directly? Maybe I'm missing but using reflection seems unnecessary.

Comment: @David Lively when I have a ViewModel (almost always) I want to get the value of the property automatically, without the need to set it in the helpers parameters

Comment: Downvotes are odd.  @Omu just needs to access the "view data notation" feature thats already inside of MVC.  Not only is this possible but a foundation of how MVC works.  You downvote this approach and you downvote MVC.

Comment: i voted which negate the downvote :) this is a pretty usefull question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ViewData.Eval(string expression)?

[ViewDataDictionary.Eval Method (System.Web.Mvc)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.eval.aspx)

Comment: ya, that's the thing, too bad it doesn't work for stuff like Html.My("Prop[0].Stuff")